# W3C XHTML 1.0 Validator - was support for attributes "Integrity" and "Crossorigin" ever added?

Tags: xhtml, w3c

When trying to validate my Home page using the W3C validator I get the following errors.

> Line 13, Column 92: there is no attribute "integrity" ….js"
> type="text/javascript"
> integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo…
>
> Line 13, Column 158: there is no attribute "crossorigin"
> …FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
> crossorigin="anonymous">

This issue has only come to light following a recent program update. It seems that the developer has only just included these attributes. There is a thread (now 5 years old) relating to this and the W3C validator. Was checking and support for Integrity and Crossorigin ever added?

```
if($isConnected) {
    echo "<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" integrity=\"sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\n";
    echo "<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" integrity=\"sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\n";
}
else {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">// <![CDATA[\nwindow.jQuery || document.write(\"<script src='{$cms['tngpath']}js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=910'>\\x3C/script>\")\n//]]></script>\n";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">// <![CDATA[\nwindow.jQuery.ui || document.write(\"<script src='{$cms['tngpath']}js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js?v=910'>\\x3C/script>\")\n//]]></script>\n";
}
```

Clearly the issue is with the two attributes as if I comment out the the first part of the code above forcing the "else" branch then I get a clean validation. However in doing this the program assumes that it is running "offline" and no off site web based content such as mapping is downloaded.

Answer (score 5):

Those attributes were introduced in HTML 5. The validator supports them in versions of the language which support them. XHTML 1.0 is too old.

Comment: Is there a more up to date online checker that I can validate against?

Comment: @Greyhound2008 — You don't seem to understand the problem. The validator you are using is **correct** (and this is an up to date on this subject as it is possible to be), the attributes you are using are not allowed in the version of HTML you are using. If you want to use the attributes, then change the version of HTML you are using and don't change the validator.

Comment: Thank you. From what I found XHTML 1.0 seems to be based on HTML4.0